# c language fibonacci squence

Tags: c, fibonacci

```c
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int fib1=0,fib2=1,fib3,limit,count = 0;
    printf("Enter the number uptill which the seriese has to be generated\n");
    scanf("%d",&limit);
    printf("===THE FIBONACCI SERIES IS===\n");
    printf("%d\n",&fib1);
    printf("%d\n",&fib2);
    count=2;
    while (count<limit){
        fib3=fib1 + fib2;
        count++;
        printf("%d\n",fib3);
        fib1=fib2;
        fib2=fib3;
    }
    return 0;
        

}
```

the `&`symbol after fib 1 variable is affecting the program but I don't know why any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Instead of printf("%d\n",&fib1);
    printf("%d\n",&fib2); you need to write printf("%d\n",fib1);
    printf("%d\n",fib2);

Comment: Also don't return 0 from void main function.

Comment: The answer was in plain sight in `printf("%d\n",fib3);`. The `&` operator takes the address (location) of the variable, which `scanf()` needs to store the input value. But `printf()` is quite different, although it looks similar, and it needs the actual values (for integer arguments).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, you are printing the addresses of `fib1` and `fib2`.

```
    printf("%d\n",&fib1);
    printf("%d\n",&fib2);
```

You should be printing their values.

```
    printf("%d\n", fib1);
    printf("%d\n", fib2);
```

You are likely confused because you would pass the address to `scanf`, but that is because `scanf` needs to *modify* the value of those variables, so it needs their address is memory. The `printf` function does not need to modify the data, so a copy of the value is all it needs.